# How To Move Continiously Multiple UIButtons in Specific Directions?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, core-animation

I have  five UIButtons in my application.All these UIButtons are stored in Array.As my Code Show below

```
  NSMutableArray *Buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:btn1, btn2, btn3,btn4,btn5, nil];
```

Now i Want to move all these UIButtons in Specific Direction Continiously.As my image show below

[image]

I Already did some animation in CAkeyframeAnimation,but As a iOS beginer  its difficult for me to perform these type of  Continious Animation on multiple UIButtons using CAKeyframeAnimation.Can some one help me about this.Any help will be appriated.

Comment: in which way do u want to move... all btns replacing their positions in a circular.. or moving all at single Point..?

Comment: @vishy thanx for quick response i want to move all these btns in way that i mention in Red arrows.all these btns take start from lower half of my view as i show three arrows,but i want to move all these btns continiously using NStimer or any other optinal which u suggest.?

Comment: @lena the `CADisplayLink` based method in my answer below is quite similar to a `NSTimer` method, and it synchronizes to the display refresh rate. Check it out and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you've done already, but you could use UIView Animations and then make sure you enable set the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction option.

You can then put a gesture recognizer on the buttons.

To get it to animate, just use UIView's block based animations, there are only 4 that need to be done, and have them repeat. It's fiddly, but it's a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: thanx for quick response Oh really useful suggestion.thanx

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to move these buttons around in a way that keeps them reactive to user touches, using Core Animation directly is probably not your best bet. My answer below is based on this assumption.

When a Core Animation-based animation is running, the layer you see moving on screen (the "presentation layer" — see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html) for more info about this) does not register touches at its current position, but only at the final position of the animation, which is invisible for the user. Thus the moving bouton will behave most of the time as if it is disabled. Though it is possible to hack around this, it is not very convenient and not meant to be used that way.

Another drawback is that `CAAnimation` is not very flexible once created, for example it would be tedious to stop the movement of the buttons at their current position if you ever needed to.

Instead, you should compute and move your `UIButtons` frames manually. To synchronize the movement with the display refresh rate and have a smooth animation, use [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html), which is a very easy to use class that you can use to register a method that will be called back each time the display is being refreshed. In this method you should update your views frames based on the desired behavior of your views.